Why pts/1 shows a login using root
I am running Ubuntu in WSL. Listing current process shows pts/1 is logged in by root. But I have only a single logged-in user "mshah" which is on pts/0
If I login to a another session it opens on pts/2. I killed the process running on pts/1 (366) but any new session never uses pts/1. And whenever I start ubuntu after a complete reboot (including the Windows host), the pts/1 is again taken by root.
I am curious to know why root is logging in on pts/1 and what is exactly happening? I did not notice this behaviour on another remote Linux server.

Output from command "w" and "tty are shown below respectively.
Why does output from "w" say user ID (mshah) is on pts/1 despite tty showing its on pts/0?


Looks fine to me, what makes you think /bin/login is a nefarious process?

But why is that process there and keep pts/1 occupied? And as I mentioned, after killing it returns after a reboot. So why is root invoking /bin/login
